# error:NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: laravel

`error:NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

My route: `Route::resource('mof/technology','TechnologyController');`

Comment: And what is your request?

Comment: And what is the content of `TechnologyController`?

Comment: If you show `TechnologyController`, we can assist you more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on server request(get/post) use like this then it will work

**Route::get('mof/technology',['as' => 'mof/technology','uses' =>'TechnologyController']);**

Comment: This is not a solution and `Resource` is not matter GET or POST.